# FastCGI: Unable to open primary script on NGinx and PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I am apparently not the only one with this problem, but after trying every suggested solution for couple I reached I point where I don't know what to do.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, NGinx and PHP-FPM.

The nginx.conf is the default one, I only set a more informative log format.

The user rights seem to be okay: NGinx and PHP_FPM run under user www-data. Document-Root owner is www-data. FPM-Pool owner is www-data. Socket-file is there and writable.

I already tried setting folder- and file-permissions to the weakest (chmod 777): No result.

This is my server.conf, as you can see from commented lines, I tried a bunch of tricks - with no effect:

```
server {
    listen         8080;
#    listen         8080 default_server;
 #   listen         [::]:8080 default_server;
    server_name    example.com www.example.com
    root           /var/www/nginx/;
    index          index.php;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/scripts.log scripts;


    gzip             on;
    gzip_comp_level  3;
    gzip_types       text/plain text/css application/javascript image/*;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if ($uri !~ "^/uploads/") {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm-www.sock;

        }

    include fastcgi.conf;

#    include         snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;

  }

    # Block access to .htaccess
    location ~ \.htaccess {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

That's the fpm-pool config:

```
[www]
listen = /run/php/php-fpm-$pool.sock
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
php_admin_flag[allow_url_include] = off
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
chroot = /var/www/nginx/
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
catch_workers_output = yes
```

This is the output of the nginx' access.log:

```
/var/www/nginx/index.php > GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
```

And that's the actual error.log:

```
2018/08/29 17:34:27 [error] 24020#24020: *47 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/nginx/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.61.37.18, server: example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php-fpm-www.sock:", host: "example.com:8080"
```

Comment: chmod will not help with `No such file or directory`. The problem is you chrooted php-fpm.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I am aware of that, but it looks like I did not understand the effects. I found the solution, will post it in a second, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the error for myself after the hint of @michael - thanks for the enlightenment.

I am using chroot, because the goal is to "jail" every website in it's own **environment** / folder. So I set the root of this particular **environment** to the real filesystem location */var/www/nginx*.

Inside the server configuration of NGinx I pass the fastcgi parameter SCRIPT_FILENAME with a leading $document_root.

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

In NGinx $document_root references the root-directive. The $document_root is, of course */var/www/nginx*

But the PHP-**environment** has a "changed root" (/ means /var/www/nginx). That means, that PHP now is looking for index.php in the folder /var/www/nginx. But as the root folder is only "virtual", PHP's /var/www/nginx actualy points to this location on the real filesystem: /var/www/nginx/var/www/nginx.

So changing the parameter to this will fix the error.

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: In my case I fixed this issue by editing `/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf` and replacing the old line with `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;` (basically the same fix formulated slightly different, but just in case it's helpful to someone).